# Ordering is not correct in TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, treeset, lru

I'm trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/description/.

I'm using treeset to save unique keys and order them based on when it's inserted. The treeset is not returning elements in the way I specified using Camparator.

```java
class LRUCache {

    Map<Integer, Integer> keyValue;// ()
    TreeSet<Pair> keys; //key, timestamp (1,-1000)
    int capacity;//2
    int timestamp;
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        keyValue = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        keys = new TreeSet<>((Pair a,Pair b) -> {
            System.out.println("inside comparator implementation");
            int result = a.x == b.x ? 0 : a.y - b.y == 0 ? -1 : a.y - b.y;
            System.out.println("result: " + result);
            return result;
        });
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int get(int key) {

        timestamp++;
        Pair pair = new Pair(key, timestamp);
        boolean found = keys.contains(pair);
        if (found) {
            System.out.println("keys contains " + key + ". So, removing it to update");
            keys.remove(pair);
        } else {
            System.out.println("keys doesn't contains " + key + ". So, not removing it. Directly adding it");
        }

        boolean added = keys.add(pair);
        System.out.println("add status: " + added + " for: " + pair);

        return keyValue.getOrDefault(key, -1);
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        int priority = Integer.MIN_VALUE + timestamp++;
        Pair pair = new Pair(key, priority);
        System.out.println("key: " + key + " priority: " + priority);
        boolean found = keys.contains(pair);
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("keys doesn't " + key + " and " + value + ". So, adding to keys");
            keys.add(pair);
        } else {
            System.out.println("keys contains " + key + " and " + value + ". So, not adding to keys");
        }

        keyValue.put(key, value);
        if (keys.size() > capacity) {
            System.out.println("size > capacity");
            Pair remove = keys.first();
            System.out.println("removing: " + remove);
            keys.remove(remove);
            keyValue.remove(remove.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LRUCache lruCache = new LRUCache(2);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("putting 1,1");
        lruCache.put(1, 1);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("putting 2,2");
        lruCache.put(2, 2);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("getting 1");
        System.out.println(lruCache.get(1));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("c");
        lruCache.put(3, 3);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("getting 2");
        System.out.println(lruCache.get(2));
    }
}
```

```java
class Pair{
    int x;
    int y;
    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("inside pair equals");
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Pair)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.x == ((Pair) o).x;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I'm expecting (2, -2147483647) to be dropped after adding (3,3), since (2, -2147483647) has negative timestamp.

This is the set that is printed before I expected (2, -2147483647) is removed.
`[Pair{x=1, y=3}, Pair{x=2, y=-2147483647}, Pair{x=3, y=-2147483645}]`

Why is `Pair{x=1, y=3}` first compared to `{x=2, y=-2147483647}`.
I wrote the comparator to order in treeset based on y values, why is it working as expected?

I tried creating a TreeSetPractise

```java
public class TreeSetPractise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Pair> ts = new TreeSet<>(( a,  b) -> {
            System.out.println("inside comparator implementation");
            int result = a.x == b.x ? 0 : a.y - b.y == 0 ? -1 : a.y - b.y;
            System.out.println("result: " + result);
            return result;
        });
        ts.add(new Pair(1,10));
        ts.add(new Pair(2, -20));
        ts.add(new Pair(3, 30));
        System.out.println(ts);
        for (Pair i : ts) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class Pair {
    int x;
    int y;
    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is working as expected.

The main problem here is, for the elements of TreeSet:Pair{x,y} has to check equality on x and ordering on y.
Meaning Set functionality is based on x and Tree functionality is based on y.

**Update**: Most of the comments/answers points out here that my comparator is wrong. The only problem with it might be overflow, but there is no problem with logic.
Also, the bigger problem for me is, TreeSet is considering two objects to be equal if comparator is returning 0. Shouldn't it call equals method on if compareTo returns 0?

Comment: Your comparator is incorrect.  CAREFULLY evaluate (by hand) the results of different comparisons and check the results against the definition of what a `Comparator` should return.

Comment: Nowadays, almost nobody should write a Comparator by hand. Use `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...)` and mistakes like this don't happen.

Comment: @JimGarrison : I did that. I know if a,b are passed and value returns negative, a comes first, 0 means they are considered equal, postive means b comes first.
i can't use Comparator.comparing because sometimes timestamps could be same, but key could be different. I want the ordering based on y and equality based on x.

Comment: @Sören :  I want the ordering based on y and equality based on x, the functions don't handle this scenario

Comment: That sounds broken. But let's try it like this: How should these pairs be sorted? `[1,1]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,3]`, `[2,1]`, `[2,2]`, `[2,3]`, `[3,1]`, `[3,2]`, `[3,3]`.

Comment: I strongly suspect this condition: `a.y - b.y == 0 ? -1` not only breaking the contract of `Comparator.compare()` - see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)): "The implementor must ensure that `signum(compare(x, y)) == -signum(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`."

Comment: @Rajesh You have an integer arithmetic overflow when you calculate `3 - -2147483647` inside your comparator, resulting in the "wrong" value `-2147483646`.

Comment: @Sören: if I just call add [1,1]: [2,1], [3,1] (my use case is [1,3],[2,3],[3,3] finally, which I'm trying by removing if it's set and adding again)

Comment: @Progman: I think that might be the issue, I'm checking it

Comment: That sounds like it is not a valid comparator.  If you can't build it with Comparator.comparing, it almost certainly doesn't really work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman does it mean i should use different data structure for set and different data structure for ordering or look for alternate solutions?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: “order them based on when it's inserted” — what does comparing x have to do with when it is inserted?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the comparator logic:

```java
int result = a.x == b.x ? 0 : a.y - b.y == 0 ? -1 : a.y - b.y;
```

There are a few issues with `a.y - b.y == 0 ? -1 : a.y - b.y`.

1. if `a.y` equals `b.y` then it considers `a < b`, which is likely not intended.
2. otherwise performs an arithmetic operation, which might overflow, and thus provide the wrong result, when `b.y` can be a large negative number like `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

If the goal is to compare `y` if `x` is not the same, you can replace that part with `a.y == b.y ? 0 : (a.y < b.y) ? - 1 : 1`. However, a safer (less error prone) approach is to just use `Integer.compare` to compare `a.y` and `b.y`.

```java
int result = a.x == b.x ? 0 : Integer.compare(a.y, b.y);
```

Comment: side note: `a.y - b.y == 0` is better written as `a.y == b.y`, not only to avoid confusion...

Comment: “If the goal is to compare y if x is the same,” you have to do the opposite of what you’re doing. `a.x == b.x ? 0 : Integer.compare(a.y, b.y)` is comparing *y* when *x* is different. It should be striking that the condition will never produce the result of comparing *x*.

Comment: it was a typo, edited the answer to make it right. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Oh boy. Let's start with the big issues:

1. The problem statement requires get and put be O(1) operations, but TreeSet.put() and TreeSet.get() take O(log n) time. That is, a TreeSet is too slow.
2. If you order your TreeSet by key first, and age second, you can lookup by key in O(log n), but key.first() is the smallest rather than the oldest entry, which causes the wrong key to be evicted. If you order by age first, and key second, you can not lookup by key. There is no odering that supports both efficient lookup by key (regardless of age), and efficient lookup by age (regardless of key). You can have either, but not both. You could use two different TreeMaps - one ordered by age, one ordered by key, that map the age to the key, and the key to the age, but that gets rather complex.

And finally, your code is rather complicated for what it does.

The simple way to implement a LRUCache in Java is this:

```
class LRUCache<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {
    final int capacity;

    LRUCache(int capacity) {
        super(10, 0.75f, true);
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > capacity;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the class name of the super class, the data is kept in a map for fast lookup, with a linked list for keeping track of access order. To maintain the list in access order, we remove the node on access (which is O(1)), and then add it to the tail of the list (which is O(1)).

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by rph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78117569/642706) correctly diagnoses your problem. I'll add a few more points.

### Harmonize your `equals`/`hashCode` with your `Comparator`

As Comments discussed, the logic of your override of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) (and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())) must be in harmony with your [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

### Record

You could more briefly declare your `Pair` class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

In a `record`, by default, the compiler implicitly creates an overriding `equals` and `hashCode` implementation that examines each and every member field. So less work for you.

```
record Point ( int x , int y ) {}
```

### `Comparator` builder

As commented, avoid your errors by building a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) via the convenience methods (`…comparing…`). See [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)).

**Important:** Notice in code below that our `Comparator` implementation considers each and every field (`x` & `y`), to be consistent with the default `equals` (and `hashCode`) implementations of our `record`.

By the way, you can refer to your `TreeSet` as the more general [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html).

```java
NavigableSet < Point > ts = new TreeSet <>(
        Comparator
                .comparingInt( Point :: x )
                .thenComparingInt( Point :: y )
);
```

As of Java 21, [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) is the more general super-interface of [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html)/`SortedSet`. See [*JEP 431*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431). Even more general is [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html).

```
SequencedSet <Pair> ts = new TreeSet<> …
```

### Complete example

```java
package work.basil.example.collections;

import java.util.*;

public class TreeSetOrdering
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        record Point( int x , int y ) { }

        SequencedSet < Point > ts = new TreeSet <>(
                Comparator
                        .comparingInt( Point :: x )
                        .thenComparingInt( Point :: y )
        );

        ts.addAll(
                List.of(
                        new Point( 7 , 42 ) ,
                        new Point( 11 , 22 ) ,
                        new Point( 1 , 2 )
                )
        );
        System.out.println( "ts = " + ts );
    }
}
```

> ts = [Point[x=1, y=2], Point[x=7, y=42], Point[x=11, y=22]]

Comment: You shouldn't keep the lambda at all if you write the comparator using `comparingInt`, right? This is how it should look: `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Point::x).thenComparingInt(Point::x))`

Comment: @Lii Quite true. I fixed the code now. And I added a full example of tested code. Thank you!